# Are tags allowed in question's titles?

Tags: support, faq, questions, tags

Is it fine to write a title like the following ones?

- Views: How do I create a list of OG groups for which the current user has edit privileges?
- Views/jQuery/jCarousel/Galleria/Colorbox - best practice?
- Content types - How to disable the title field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding tags to the title, it would be better to make the title more descriptive, considering that tags are visible on any page listing questions.

[image: screenshot]

Better titles should be similar to the following ones:

- How do I create a list of OG groups for which the current user has edit privileges?
- How do I disable the title field for content types?

The second title should be rewritten to be more descriptive; taking off the tags from the title what is left is "Galleria - best practice" that doesn't give any clue about what the question is asking.