# What is considered a good post edit?

Tags: support, faq, editing, suggested-edits

Is there any suggestions about what it is considering good editing in posts? What kind of things should I not edit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The block that is shown to the users who don't have the privilege of editing every post contains the following points:

1. Fix grammatical, or spelling errors
2. Clarify meaning without changing it
3. Correct minor mistakes
4. Add related resources or links
5. Always respect the original author

To this, I would add the following clarifications:

- The first point doesn't mean to change the spelling of a word from British English to American English, or vice versa. It is probably better to have a consistent spelling, though.
- The third point is not valid for code shown in a post: If the code is using the wrong function, leave a comment to the post author. Even in the case the user wrote the function name with a typo, leave a comment, and let the user change the code.
- The edit should not be too minor: Always edit as much as possible in a post. Bear in mind that the suggested edits are reviewed from one or more users; when you are suggesting an edit, make the time they take to review worth it. If, for example, you are going to correct the spelling of *I* (first person singular) from *i*, correct every occurrence of the pronoun.
- If you see a post that refers a module without linking it, add a link, and (possibly) an excerpt from the project page.
- If you see a post containing a link to a screenshot, change the link to show the screenshot in the post page.
- If you see code that is poorly formatted, re-format it to make it more readable; for example, remove the empty lines that are present, and which make the code take more vertical space than necessary.
- If you see a tag in the title, remove it, or edit the title to insert the tag organically and conversationally.
- Don't highlight random words; if you see random words being highlighted, change them.
- Don't use code formatting to highlight random words; removed that formatting when you see it being used for something that is not code or that would not be escaped because using characters that have a special meaning in HTML.

#### See also

- [When editing a post, should I Americanize spelling?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/951/when-editing-a-post-should-i-americanize-spelling)
- [I see a question with poorly formatted code. Should I fix it?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/948/i-see-a-question-with-poorly-formatted-code-should-i-fix-it)
- [What should be done with questions that give the link for the code instead of showing it?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/855/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-give-the-link-for-the-code-instead-of-sh)
- [Are tags allowed in question's titles?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/838/are-tags-allowed-in-questions-titles)

Comment: so i like to highlight drupal keywords. does the community approve or disapprove of that. If someone has really low rep (like ~500) and they're struggling with a view i believe highlighting drupal verbiage is key to learning and understanding by those we help.

Comment: Highlighting words in a given answer doesn't help as providing links to project pages or documentation. Highlighting a word doesn't mean telling the users what that word means, but a link to the documentation helps users to better understand a concept that has been barely touched in an answer.